# How many bytes does it take to store a certain amount of Letters in base64 string

Tags: c++, ascii

How many bytes would it take to store `AAAAA`?
I know that one ASCII letter takes one byte, but this line of code below gives me a weird answer.

```
nbytesdecoded = ((ch + 3) / 4) * 3; Where ch is the length of characters, which is five.
```

The code above gives me 6 bytes required. Is this right?

The code is below.

```
int nprbytes;

int nbytesdecoded;

char *s = new char[256]; 
char *bufin = new char[256]; 

cout << "Enter your phrase: ";
cin >> s;


bufin = (char *)s;
int ch = strlen(s);
ch = ch - 1;

nbytesdecoded = ((ch + 3) / 4) * 3;

cout << nbytesdecoded;
```

Comment: It depends on the format. ASCII proper takes 7 bits, The GSM SMS default encoding takes 7 bits.... UTF-16 takes 16 bits, UTF-8 takes a variable number. If you do base64 or uuencode or some other 7-bit clean they take more than one byte... C-strings you have to account for the null termination....

Comment: What exactly is that formula supposed to represent? if it really is number of bytes, you're going to get decimal answers most of the time.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this code I got. It is for decoding Base64 string.

Comment: Please include that this is number of bytes required to decode a base64 string.

Comment: <nitpick>UTF-16 takes 16 or 32 bits</nitpick>.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you're giving `AAAAA` as a string literal. This is because every string gets suffixed by a null terminating character `\0` which is an extra byte.

To get storage of 5 bytes you would need to use a character array and not treat it as a string

E.g

```
char ch[5] = {'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'};
```

Comment: I declared my char like 
`char *s = (char*)malloc(256); s[0] = '\0';`

Comment: That will set the first character to `\0` only, that doesn't help with assigning a string with say `strcpy` or the like.

Comment: Ok. I see. I used strlen and subtracted one from the int length.

Comment: Used `strlen` on what? I need to see more code to tell you whether your code is correct :P

Comment: Also, you should be using `new`, not `malloc` in c++

Comment: I doubt that the terminating null character has anything to do with the proportion of bytes used in clear text versus Base64 encoding. But at the time of this answer the OP had probably not yet informed us in a comment what the question was about. It's hard to be a telepath these days.

Answer (score 0):

Base64 means that every character in the output text encodes 6 bit (64 possible combinations) of input data. Assuming that your string is encoded as one octet per character, that means five characters take 40 bits. Divided by 6 and rounded up, I get 7.

BTW: Base64 is so commonplace, that you could use an existing implementation in whatever programming language you have and test for yourself. Also, you have misread the code, as the number is **nbytesdecoded**, which suggests that it is the number after decoding the Base64 string, but even then it is still wrong.